# Convert two columns in pyspark dataframe into one python dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe in which I want to use two of its columns to output a dictionary.

input pyspark dataframe:

```
col1|col2|col3
v   |  3 | a
d   |  2 | b
q   |  9 | g
```

output:

> `dict = {'v': 3, 'd': 2, 'q': 9}`

how should I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can achieve it by converting the DF (with only the two columns you want) to rdd:

```
data_rdd = data.selet(['col1', 'col2']).rdd
```

create a rdd containing key, pair with both columns using rdd.map function:

```
kp_rdd = data_rdd.map(lambda row : (row[0],row[1]))
```

and then collect as map:

```
dict = kp_rdd.collectAsMap()
```

that's the main idea, sorry I don't have an instance of pyspark running right now to test it.

Answer (score 2):

Given your example, after selecting the applicable columns and converting to an rdd, `collectAsMap` will accomplish the desired dictionary without any additional steps:

`df.select('col1', 'col2').rdd.collectAsMap()`

Answer (score 1):

few different options here depending on the format needed ... check this out ... am using structured api ... if you need to persist then either save as json dict or preserve schema with parquet

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json
from pyspark.sql.functions import create_map
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = spark\
.createDataFrame([\
    ('v', 3, 'a'),\
    ('d', 2, 'b'),\
    ('q', 9, 'g')],\
    ["c1", "c2", "c3"])

mapDF = df.select(create_map(col("c1"), col("c2")).alias("mapper"))
mapDF.show(3)

+--------+
|  mapper|
+--------+
|[v -> 3]|
|[d -> 2]|
|[q -> 9]|
+--------+

dictDF = df.select(to_json(create_map(col("c1"), col("c2")).alias("mapper")).alias("dict"))
dictDF.show()

+-------+
|   dict|
+-------+
|{"v":3}|
|{"d":2}|
|{"q":9}|
+-------+

keyValueDF = df.selectExpr("(c1, c2) as keyValueDict").select(to_json(col("keyValueDict")).alias("keyValueDict"))
keyValueDF.show()

+-----------------+
|     keyValueDict|
+-----------------+
|{"c1":"v","c2":3}|
|{"c1":"d","c2":2}|
|{"c1":"q","c2":9}|
+-----------------+
```